# How to create a new user in a controller with Spring Security?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to create a registration form for users with Spring Secutiry and Spring MVC. I want to use SpringSecurity 3.2 and JavaConfig.

How can I create a new save user and save it in a controller method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Spring does not handle registration of new users, and other flows such as "forgot password", "change password", etc. So you have to create your own forms.

[I wrote a project](https://github.com/OhadR/authentication-flows) that handle these flows, and a client with sample forms. You can have a look there, it might help.

Comment: it means that I must create a complete api only to create a user from the controller. I would like to create users without any details. Only username and password. I would like to do something like authenticationManager.createUser(...) . A

Answer (score 0):

Jonathan,

You could use [JdbcUserDetailsManager](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManager.html) as an API to manage your User object. However, for passwords, you have to apply the new one using an encoder, for example `ShaPasswordEncoder.encodePassword()`.

Comment: Using SHA to encode passwords is, security-wise, not very wise. SHA is a (cryptographic) hash, but is not designed to thwart brute-force attacks. Use Bcrypt instead (used by default in Spring Security)